# Why and how is IE11 UA string spoofed when visiting specific sites?

Tags: internet-explorer

When visiting certain sites with IE11 (such as [www.walgreens.com](https://www.walgreens.com)), the following UA string is emitted by the browser:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0)
```

...but for most other sites the expected IE11 UA string is sent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

What is the underlying mechanism at work here?  Why is `MSIE 9.0` being sent?  It doesn't seem like it has anything to do with the server response, since the request and its headers are fully sent before receiving a response (from what I understand).  It's not clear to me what information the browser is using to make this distinction.

Comment: I figured out what is happening:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622935(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 have an option to download a list from a Microsoft server that tells IE to use specific compatibility settings for specific sites. You can view a version of this list [here](https://iecvlist.microsoft.com/IE11/1375395130872/iecompatviewlist.xml) and will see that Walgreens.com is listed with the info to use compatibility to IE 9.

If you want to disable this behaviour on the client, disable the option "download compatibility list from Microsoft" in the Compatibility View Settings of Internet Explorer.

If you own the domain Walgreens.com, you have to contact Microsoft, so they take you from the list.